# log File not generating in log4j

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

I am new to log4j. I have created a sample java program implementing log4j in it.

Below is the java program:

```
package logging;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class Logging {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logging.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

         logger.trace("This is a Trace");
         logger.debug("This is a Debug");
         logger.info("This is an Info");
         logger.warn("This is a Warn");
         logger.error("This is an Error");
         logger.fatal("This is a Fatal");

    }

}
```

I am getting the output in the console screen.But the ***log file is not*** getting generated. I have also configured my project in the Eclipse neon using the following link:
[Configuration](http://syncor.blogspot.in/2013/09/getting-started-with-log4j-2-in-eclipse.html)

I have done everything good. But the log file is not generating.When I implement log4j programmatically the file is getting generated.The following is my **properties file:**

```
#root

log4j.logger.com.apress.logging.log4j=debug,dest

log4j.additivity.com.apress.logging.log4j=false

#define the appender
log4j.appender.dest = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

#set the name of the file 
log4j.appender.dest.File=${user.home}/log.out

#setting the immediate flush to true (default) 
log4j.appender.dest.ImmediateFlush=true

#setting the threshold
log4j.appender.dest.Threshold=ERROR

#setting the append to false, overwrite 
log4j.appender.dest.Append=true

#set the DatePattern 
log4j.appender.dest.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd
```

What do I need to do to have Log4J write to the log file?

Comment: check this for file appender configurations : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm

Comment: try using "-Dlog4j.configuration=your_configuration_file" ins run configuration

Comment: log4j:WARN No such property [conversion`enter] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.？？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure log4j.properties is in default package

```
# Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
    log4j.logger.infoLogger=DEBUG, infoLogger

    log4j.additivity.infoLogger = false
    # Redirect log messages to console
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

    # Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=E:\\LOG\\ConvertorLogger.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

    # Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
    log4j.appender.infoLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.infoLogger.File=E:\\LOG\\ConvertorInfoLogger.log
    log4j.appender.infoLogger.MaxFileSize=5MB
    log4j.appender.infoLogger.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.infoLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.infoLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: log4j:WARN No such property [conversion`enter] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout. ？？

Comment: What is a default package for maven?

Comment: First line of your answer solved my problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this file：log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,stdout,R
  log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c -%m%n
  log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
  log4j.appender.R.File=${user.home}/log.out
  log4j.appender.MaxFileSize=100KB
  log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
  log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = %p %t %c -%m%n
  log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to give the absolute path (for Windows, using Intellij IDEA) in my `log4j2.xml` file as following:

```
fileName="C:\Users\Fotios.Kolytoumpas\IdeaProjects\jetbrains-hibernate\logs\your-app-name.log"
```